# Is it possible to add a LinearGradient fill to an SVGPath that already has an ImagePattern Fill?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

In my main application I have some SVGPaths that I add to an XYChart. Sometimes they have an ImagePattern fill which now needs to have a LinearGradient fill. The ImagePattern fill is a crosshatch and this needs to be colored with the LinearGradient the same as if it was a solid Rectangle with a LinearGradient applied. The SVGPath also has a dotted outline and the LinearGradient should fill the dotted outline and the ImagePattern fill as it they were part of the same shape.

I've written some sample code to show where I'm at. This colors the crosshatch as it's created and looks ok but isn't the effect I describe above as each cross in the ImagePattern has the LinearGradient applied individually. Ideally the LinearGradient would just be applied to the final SVGPath once the ImagePattern fill has been applied.
I've also tried some effects using Blend and ColorInput but haven't managed to get any closer to the solution.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            List<Color> colors = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN);
            ArrayList<Stop> stops = new ArrayList<>(colors.size() * 2);

            for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
                stops.add(new Stop(getOffset(i, colors.size()), colors.get(i)));
                stops.add(new Stop(getOffset(i + 1, colors.size()), colors.get(i)));
            }

            LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 20, 20, false, CycleMethod.REPEAT, stops);

            SVGPath svgPath = new SVGPath();
            svgPath.setContent("M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z");

            Image hatch = createCrossHatch(lg);
            ImagePattern pattern = new ImagePattern(hatch, 0, 0, 10, 10, false);

            svgPath.setFill(pattern);
            svgPath.setStroke(lg);

            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            root.setCenter(svgPath);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected static Image createCrossHatch(Paint paint) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setPrefSize(20, 20);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
        Line fw = new Line(-5, -5, 25, 25);
        Line bw = new Line(-5, 25, 25, -5);
        fw.setStroke(paint);
        bw.setStroke(paint);
        fw.setStrokeWidth(3);
        bw.setStrokeWidth(3);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(fw, bw);
        new Scene(pane);
        SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
        sp.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        return pane.snapshot(sp, null);
    }

    private double getOffset(double i, int count) {
        return (((double) 1) / (double) count * (double) i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you run the supplied code you will see it draws a dog bone. The lineargradient colors of the dashed outline should continue through the cross hatch ImagePattern fill. I'm aware of why the hatched ImagePattern is colored like it is but this is the best compromise I have at present. As mentioned I'd like to be able to applied the LinearGradient fill to the whole shape once the ImagePattern fill has been applied so the LinearGradient affects the whole shape the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to apply and *combine* two paints over one single node. We can overlay many different [paints](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typepaint) (like solid, linear gradients or even image patterns) using background color via css, but that won't combine.

So in order to combine two different paints, on one side a linear gradient, on the other a pattern fill, we need to apply them to two nodes, and use a blending effect between both paints.

According to the code posted, this is the SVGPath with the linear gradient:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Node base = getNodeWithGradient();

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    Group group = new Group(base);
    root.setCenter(group);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private SVGPath getNodeWithGradient() {
    List<Color> colors = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN);
    ArrayList<Stop> stops = new ArrayList<>(colors.size() * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
        stops.add(new Stop(getOffset(i, colors.size()), colors.get(i)));
        stops.add(new Stop(getOffset(i + 1, colors.size()), colors.get(i)));
    }

    LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 20, 20, false, CycleMethod.REPEAT, stops);

    SVGPath svgPath = getSVGPath();
    svgPath.setFill(lg);
    svgPath.setStroke(lg);

    return svgPath;
}

private SVGPath getSVGPath() {
    SVGPath svgPath = new SVGPath();
    svgPath.setContent("M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z");
    return svgPath;
}

private double getOffset(double i, int count) {
    return (((double) 1) / (double) count * (double) i);
}
```

[image: Linear Gradient]

While this is the SVGPath with the image pattern fill:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Node overlay = getNodeWithPattern();

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    Group group = new Group(overlay);

    root.setCenter(group);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private SVGPath getNodeWithPattern() {
    Image hatch = createCrossHatch();
    ImagePattern pattern = new ImagePattern(hatch, 0, 0, 10, 10, false);

    SVGPath svgPath = getSVGPath();
    svgPath.setFill(pattern);

    return svgPath;
}

private SVGPath getSVGPath() {
    SVGPath svgPath = new SVGPath();
    svgPath.setContent("M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z");
    return svgPath;
}

private static Image createCrossHatch() {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.setPrefSize(20, 20);
    Line fw = new Line(-5, -5, 25, 25);
    Line bw = new Line(-5, 25, 25, -5);
    fw.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    bw.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    fw.setStrokeWidth(3);
    bw.setStrokeWidth(3);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(fw, bw);
    new Scene(pane);
    SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
    return pane.snapshot(sp, null);
}
```

[image: Image Pattern]

Now the trick is to combine both SVGPath nodes, adding a blending mode to the one on top.

According to [JavaDoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/effect/BlendMode.html#ADD) for `BlendMode.ADD`:

> The color and alpha components from the top input are added to those from the bottom input.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Node base = getNodeWithGradient();
    Node overlay = getNodeWithPattern();
    overlay.setBlendMode(BlendMode.ADD);

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    Group group = new Group(base, overlay);

    root.setCenter(group);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private SVGPath getNodeWithGradient() {
    List<Color> colors = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN);
    ArrayList<Stop> stops = new ArrayList<>(colors.size() * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
        stops.add(new Stop(getOffset(i, colors.size()), colors.get(i)));
        stops.add(new Stop(getOffset(i + 1, colors.size()), colors.get(i)));
    }

    LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 20, 20, false, CycleMethod.REPEAT, stops);

    SVGPath svgPath = getSVGPath();
    svgPath.setFill(lg);
    svgPath.setStroke(lg);
    return svgPath;
}

private SVGPath getNodeWithPattern() {
    Image hatch = createCrossHatch();
    ImagePattern pattern = new ImagePattern(hatch, 0, 0, 10, 10, false);

    SVGPath svgPath = getSVGPath();
    svgPath.setFill(pattern);
    return svgPath;
}

private SVGPath getSVGPath() {
    SVGPath svgPath = new SVGPath();
    svgPath.setContent("M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z");
    return svgPath;
}

private static Image createCrossHatch() {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.setPrefSize(20, 20);
    Line fw = new Line(-5, -5, 25, 25);
    Line bw = new Line(-5, 25, 25, -5);
    fw.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    bw.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    fw.setStrokeWidth(3);
    bw.setStrokeWidth(3);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(fw, bw);
    new Scene(pane);
    SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
    return pane.snapshot(sp, null);
}

private double getOffset(double i, int count) {
    return (((double) 1) / (double) count * (double) i);
}
```

And we get the desired result:

[image: Linear Gradient + Image Pattern]

Comment: Clear and thorough answer as always Jose, thank you very much :)